# True False Drivers

Tags: python, drivers

I'd like to enable/disable a constraint based on 'influence' being 0 or 1. Here is a picture of my situation. I think I'm very close, I'm just not sure how to tell Blender the command.

Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why control the visibility with the influence? But anyway...

So you need to:

1. Get the influence into the visibility driver.
2. Turn that number into a boolean with python.
   Both of these should be fairly easy, so most of it is preference.

First, right click the influence and hit "copy as new driver."
Second, right click the visibility and hit "paste as new driver."
Third, right click the visibility again and hit "edit driver."
Fourth, change the "type" from "averaged value" to "scripted expression."
Fifth, in the scripting field, change "influence" to "not bool(influence)".
That should do it :)

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!!! :)